# Using stof or strtof (string to float) in C++ compiled to Webassembly gives me a runtime error

Tags: c++, webassembly, smartcontracts, eos

I am writing an eosio smart contract, which is basically C++ compiled to Webassembly.

When using **stof** or **strtof** (string to float), I get the error `cause: access violation\n${callstack}`when running the action (basically a function). Interestingly, **stoi** works fine.

Example code

```
//Will both give the error for any string
//including both valid float representations (e.g. "10.23")
//and also invalid float representations (e.g. "Hello World")
ACTION testcontract::parser1(string text) {
  float val = stof(text);
}
ACTION testcontract::floatparser2(string text) {
  float val = strtof(text.c_str(), nullptr);
}

//Will work
ACTION testcontract::intparser(string text) {
  uint32_t val = stoi(text);
}
```

Is this because of some design restrictions of Webassembly? Should this work in Webassembly in general (without the eosio smart contract on top of it). Or am I just doing something wrong here?

Comment: We have no idea what `text` consists of.  Why not hardcode a floating point string and test?  `float val = stof("1.2");`

Comment: Does this happen always, or only for specific input?  The functions may throw an exception if they get garbage input.

Comment: You're not checking for any failures from `strtof()` in particular.

Comment: My bad, I should have clarified. stof / strtof give this error for any input.
I specifically tested `float val = stof("1.2");`, which also gave this error

Comment: please run the EOS-vm under a debugger (gdb) and try to get a backtrace